# Sorting related objects in the Django Admin form interface

Tags: django, django-admin

I am looking to sort the related objects that show up when editing an object using the admin form.  So for example, I would like to take the following object:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField( ... )
    last_name = models.CharField( ... )
    hero = models.ForeignKey( 'self', null=True, blank=True )
```

and edit the first name, last name and hero using the admin interface.  I want to sort the objects as they show up in the drop down by last name, first name (ascending).  How do I do that?

*Context*

- I'm using Django v1.1.
- I started by looking for help in the [django admin docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/), but didn't find the solution
- As you can see in the example, the foreign key is pointing to itself, but I expect it would be the same as pointing to a different model object.
- **Bonus points** for being able to filter the related objects, too (eg~ only allow selecting a hero with the same first name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField( ... )
    last_name = models.CharField( ... )
    hero = models.ForeignKey( 'self', null=True, blank=True )
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-last_name', 'first_name']
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering

Note: According to the SVN docs, the admin only uses the first of the ordering options, so this is the closest you're gettig to what you want.

Comment: Oh, I thought the docs were saying that Meta.ordering is the default ordering when *browsing* the objects.  I didn't realize it would apply to the dropdown when editing.  Thanks!  I'm off to try it out. **Edit** - confirmed and accepted :)